# Python missing data in body

Tags: python, post, request

Hello i'm using `request` to perform some http calls. The is a strange behaviour, the response should contain a list of items, but i only get one item.

This is the result i get from Postman when performing the call:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "code": "sample_code",
        "amount": "90.00",
        "is_available": true,
    }, 
    {
        "code": "sample_code1",
        "amount": "30.00",
        "is_available": false,
    },
    {
        "code": "sample_code2",
        "amount": "333.00",
        "is_available": true,
    }]
}
```

With this is the reponse i get in my script :

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "code": "sample_code2",
        "amount": "333.00",
        "is_available": true,
    }]
}
```

this is how i perform the action :

```
 for product in sorted(products):
    jsonObject  = requests.post(endpoint,json=payload, verify=False).json
    print(jsonObject)
```

it's like it returns only the last element. I could not figure out why.

EDIT added request:

```
  {
 
  "locale": "en-GB",
  "products": [
    {
      "categories": [
        "T-Shirt"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "basketTotal": {
    "amount": "42",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  "requestDateTime": "2021-04-16T10:53:45.770Z",
  "stock": {
    "isReplen": false
  }
}
```

Comment: please check the headers and data which you send in postman is same as you send in script

Comment: Checked but have not found anything different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and then the solution. Going deep reading https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request, instead of giving a JSON ojbect i could send a string *payload* that encodes a JSON.
So my code now is :

```
requests.post(url,headers=header, data=payload, verify=False)
```

and return the list of items correctly, i've added an header : `'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=Latin-1` because i need it later.